# Children's book series: alternative world, metal woven into clothes for warmth

Tags: story-identification

I remember reading a series of books in junior school, with a boy who travelled to an alternative world - I remember it being cold, and they had special metal woven into their clothes to keep them warm.  Ship were involved ... and I remember a cat was significant.

Does anyone remember this!?

Comment: Can you give a timeframe for when you were in Jr High?

Comment: Is it any of these? Your details are scant. As someone said in comments, when were you in jr high? (Gives a no-later-than publication date.) And are you certain it was a cat, not a dog or some other animal? (People mis-remember sometimes.)
http://ask.metafilter.com/231367/Fantasy-novels-featuring-talking-cats-telepathic-cats-sentient-cats-intelligent-cats-etc

Answer (score 4):

This suggests "[Have Space Suit—Will Travel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Have_Space_Suit%E2%80%94Will_Travel)" by Robert Heinlein. Young Kip wins a spacesuit in a contest. He rebuilds it, and ends up going on an adventure with a young girl and a vaguely cat-like creature called the "Mother-thing." They are all kidnapped by a bad-guy alien, and end up going to Pluto, where Kip nearly freezes to death in the process of getting help. There's a big trial at the end.

The books were reprinted about the time I was in school, and the cover picture had the Mother-thing looking sort of like a puma. Does this sound helpful?

[image: Cover of "Have Space Suit - Will Travel" by Robert A. Heinlein. "Kip was willing to give up a lot to get to the Moon - but he never expected it to be his life! The cover shows a figure in a spacesuit kneeling down holding an animal, while a second figure in a spacesuit runs towards them.]

Comment: Out of curiosity, was there metal woven into the suits for warmth?